# Facing deployment issue with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I wanted to test a little application that can read a specific directory in my file system. 
When using eclipse with tomcat it works fine but when i try to deploy the war in the wepApps directory of my installed tomcat.7, it sadly crashs (see exception below). I've also added a permission to my application in catalina.policy but nothing's change.

Permission :

```
//the permission used to grant read/write to test directory for readSystemFile
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/readSystemFile/WEB-INF/classes/-" {
    permission java.io.FilePermission
         "D:/home/dev/test/*", "read, write";
};
```

Exception:

```
GRAVE: Exception fixing docBase for context [/readSystemFile] 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\readSystemFile\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:844)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
12 févr. 2012 15:35:25 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext postWorkDirectory
ATTENTION: Failed to create work directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\work\Catalina\localhost\readSystemFile] for context [/readSystemFile]
12 févr. 2012 15:35:25 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader startInternal
GRAVE: LifecycleException 
java.io.IOException: Failed to create destination directory to copy resources
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.setRepositories(WebappLoader.java:888)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.startInternal(WebappLoader.java:603)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5079)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)
12 févr. 2012 15:35:25 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
GRAVE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommending adding a MANIFEST file next, since that's what the exception complains about.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to package the war file?  It looks like whatever program you're using isn't creating the required manifest file (and presumably other files too).  Try using eclipse's export features or use ant.

Comment: I've use Eclipse export and i've already checked that the manifest is present in the war. But it's content is : Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. Most probably it is a wrong setup of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I went through similar problem. War files placed in webapps folder was not getting deployed. In fact when i see from manager console of tomcat it was in stop state.
When i tried to start it, it was not starting any context but throwing catalina Lifecycle exceptions as given below

> FAIL - Application at context path /proj-xyz could not be started
> FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/proj-xyz]]

My machine is ubuntu and the problem was i have started tomcat without sudo

```
./startup.sh
or
./catalina.sh start
```

I think it was lagging some permissions as tomcat not started from sudo. But later i realized and used

```
sudo ./startup.sh
or
sudo ./catalina.sh start
```

It got fixed